# How to exclude modified binary files from `git status` output?

Tags: git, version-control, binaryfiles, gitattributes, git-status

We have a `.gitattributes` file to instruct git about which files are binary files - but I'm finding running `git status` is problematic in cases where we update hundreds of binary files along with a handful of source code files. It's far too easy to miss a source file name in a huge list.

Is there any way to exclude binary files from the output of `git status` or is there some alternative method to achieve the same end?

---

Addressing comments:

**Why would we need this?**

They're generated binaries from reporting software.

The circumstances arise mainly by accident when some long-running report it still running and additional work is saved while it's still running.

The problem really is that the reporter stores its data in the style of one report-generated file per source file, so it inherently updates hundreds of small JSON files which we treat as binary.

Comment: There isn't, but: why are you storing generated binary files in Git in the first place? Or, if they're not *generated* binary files, but rather simply "binary, but still source, files that must be stored per commit", why do you care about which ones are "source" (text) files, since you need to add *all* modified (i.e., source) files?

Comment: They're generated binaries. The circumstances arise mainly by accident when I start some report that takes a long time to generate and then save additional work. The problem really is that the reporter stores its data in the style of one report-generated file per source file, so it inherently updates hundreds of small JSON files which we treat as binary.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't store generated binaries in Git at all. Applying that rule would solve this problem. (Consider storing the generated binaries elsewhere, outside Git, in a cache.)

Comment: @torek thanks for your reply. I agree, and a different method for storing these is on the TODO list, but as you can imagine it's not high on that list. I've updated my question with some additional info.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this.  This is a specific instance of the question, "How do I ignore tracked files?", which is answered [in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

While this mentions checkouts, Git also doesn't provide a way to do this for `git status`.

As torek mentioned in the comments, you should not store generated files in the repository.  If you remove these files from the repository and then add the patterns for them to `.gitignore`, then users will not commit these files into the repository, and so whether a report is running when a commit happens will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `git status` *not to show you those files*.

If your report files have the attribute `report`, say

```
git status -- ':(attr:!report)*'
```

There are many other ways to do this, but that's probably the easiest to start with.